# How to pass a vector of objects of any class to a non-member function as a reference?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, vector

**This is what I have tried**

*In the prototyping of the function*

```
void display(const std::vector<movies>& v);
```

*In the function definition*

```
void display(const movies std::vector<movies>& v){
  std::cout<<v.get_name();
}
```

*The function call*

```
display(list1);
```

**When I run this i get These error**

```
  movies.cpp:52:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
  void display(const movies std::vector<movies>& v){
                                               ^
  movies.cpp:52:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
  movies.cpp:52:48: error: expected initializer before ‘v’
  void display(const movies std::vector<movies>& v){
                                                 ^
```

**Edit After suggestion from @aschepler in the comments.**
*If i remove extra "movies" from function definition.*
*Now the function definition becomes*

```
void display(const std::vector<movies>& v){
  std::cout<<v.get_name();
}
```

*Still it won't compile and now It shows some different error message.*

```
movies.cpp: In function ‘void display(const std::vector<movies>&)’:
movies.cpp:53:16: error: ‘const class std::vector<movies>’ has no 
member named ‘get_name’  std::cout<<v.get_name();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

**My full Code Is also given below if you want to go through it.**

*Also I m a beginner so please be kind.*

**definition of my class movies**

```
  movies.h file
  #pragma once
  #include<string>
  #include<vector>
    class movies{
      private:
   std::string name;
   double rating;
   int times_watched;
  public:
   static int num_movies;
  movies();
  ~movies();
   movies(std::string,double,int);
   void set_name(std::string);
   void set_rating(double);
   void set_times_watched(int);
   std::string get_name() const;
   double get_rating() const;
   int get_watch_history() const;
  };
 void display(const std::vector<movies>& v);
```

**Implementation of the class**

```
  movies.cpp file
  #include "movies.h"
  #include<iostream>
  int movies::num_movies=0;
  movies::movies()
   :name{"null"},rating{0},times_watched{0}{
      num_movies++;
  }
 movies::~movies(){
    num_movies--;
 }
 void movies::set_times_watched(int t){
    times_watched=t;
 }
 void movies::set_name(std::string nm){
     this->name=nm;
 }
void movies::set_rating(double d){
   this->rating =d;
}
std::string movies::get_name() const{
 return this->name;
}
double movies::get_rating() const{
return this->rating;
}
int movies::get_watch_history() const{
   return this->times_watched;
   }
  movies::movies(std::string na,double k,int s)
    :name{na},rating{k},times_watched{s}{
    num_movies++;
    }
    bool rating_check(double rt){
        if((rt<=5)&&(rt>=0)){
           return true;
          }else{
         return false;
       }
    }
   bool times_watched_check(int watched){
     if(watched>=0){
         return true;
       }else{
        return false;
       }
     }
void display(const movies std::vector<movies>& v){
     std::cout<<v.get_name();
   }
```

**The main program is**

```
main.cpp file
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include "movies.h"
int main(){
 std::vector<movies>list1 (1,movies());
 std::string temp {"null"},temp1;
 int num=0,flag=0;
 double temp2;
 while(temp != "n"){

 std::cout<<"enter name:";
 std::cin>>temp1;
 if(num!=0){
     for(int j=0;j<=num;j++){
         if(temp1==list1[j].get_name()){
             std::cout<<"movie already present"<<std::endl;
             flag=1;
             break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==0){
         list1[num].set_name(temp1);
          temp1.clear();
    rating:
          std::cout<<"enter your rating of movie(on a scale of 5):";
          std::cin>>temp2;
          if(rating_check(temp2)){
              list1[num].set_rating(temp2);
          }else{
              std::cout<<"Invalid Input.Please Try Again."<<std::endl;
               goto rating;
          }
   times_watched:
            std::cout<<"Number of times you have watched "<<list1[num].get_name()<<":";
            std::cin>>temp2;
          if(times_watched_check(temp2)){
              if(temp2==0){
                   std::cout<<"It means,You haven't Watched the movie.\nSo please first watch the movie."<<std::endl;
                   list1.erase(list1.begin()+num);
                   goto mv;
              }else{
                  list1[num].set_times_watched(temp2);
              }
          }else{
              std::cout<<"Invalid Input.Please Try Again."<<std::endl;
               goto times_watched;
          }
          num++;
          std::cout<<"you want to add more movies:";
          std::cin>>temp;
          if((temp=="Yes")||(temp=="yes")||(temp=="YES")||(temp=="y")||(temp=="Y")){
               list1.resize(list1.size()+1);
                continue;
            }
    }
    if(flag==1){
           mv:
              std::cout<<"do you want to add any other movie:";
              std::cin>>temp;
              if((temp=="Yes")||(temp=="yes")||(temp=="YES")||(temp=="y")||(temp=="Y")){
                   list1.resize(list1.size()+1);
                   flag=0;
                    continue;
                }else{
                    if((temp=="no")||(temp=="NO")||(temp=="n")){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        std::cout<<"Invalid Input.Please Try Again."<<std::endl;
                        goto mv;
                    }
                }
    }

   }
   display(list1);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a include file problem. When showing your code, also show the includes.

Comment: Look at the line it complains about in movies.cpp: `void display(const movies std::vector<movies>& v){` There's an extra `movies` in there.

Comment: @JasperKent thanks for the suggestion now i have edited the question to include the header files.

Comment: avoid using `goto`. It's a bad practice. Use loops or recurssions instead.

Comment: Naming tip: don't use plurals like "movies" for singular things.

Comment: @aschepler i have included what you said in the question.still the problem is not getting resolved now it shows some different error message

Comment: and thank you to @asmmo for the tip. I will keep these in mind next time i write code.

Comment: also thank you to @molbdnilo for the tip

Comment: Update your question with the code you are now compiling, and the error you are now receiving. Do you really expect help with "some different error message" without showing that message, or the code that produced it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile from this line because you are calling a function on an array of movies when you can only call the function on a single element.

```
movies.cpp:53:16: error: ‘const class std::vector<movies>’ has no 
member named ‘get_name’  std::cout<<v.get_name();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
                              ----->v[I].get_name(); **would compile
```

Perhaps the goal of your program is to have a Class called Movies that contains a vector of Movies. Otherwise, name this class movie (singular).

Comment: also, I would have commented this, but I do not have the credit to do so